# How to insert data using wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wriiten as following

```
$name="Kumkum";
$email="kumkum@gmail.com";
$phone="3456734567";
$country="India";
$course="Database";
$message="hello i want to read db";
$now = new DateTime();
$datesent=$now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');    
global $wpdb;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
 "INSERT INTO `wp_submitted_form`      (`name`,`email`,`phone`,`country`,`course`,`message`,`datesent`) values ("
 $name, $email, $phone, $country, $course, $message, $datesent. ')")';

$wpdb->query($sql);
```

It's not working... It throws error... Please help me in correcting it.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Use `$wpdb->insert()`.

```
$wpdb->insert('wp_submitted_form', array(
    'name' => 'Kumkum',
    'email' => 'kumkum@gmail.com',
    'phone' => '3456734567', // ... and so on
));
```

Addition from @mastrianni:

`$wpdb->insert` sanitizes your data for you, unlike `$wpdb->query` which requires you to sanitize your query with `$wpdb->prepare`. The difference between the two is `$wpdb->query` allows you to write your own SQL statement, where `$wpdb->insert` accepts an array and takes care of sanitizing/sql for you.

Comment: I have to add data dynamically

Comment: What do you mean dynamically? `"name" => $name,` ?

Comment: Sure, then just replace those strings with your variables.

Comment: Sorry to drudge up an old topic, but I wanted to note that `$wpdb->insert` sanitizes your data for you, unlike `$wpdb->query` which requires you to sanitize your query with `$wpdb->prepare`. The difference between the two is `$wpdb->query` allows you to write your own SQL statement, where `$wpdb->insert` accepts an array and takes care of sanitizing/sql for you.

Comment: You need a 3rd parameter indicating the data types of each parameter, otherwise they will all be trated as string. For "int, float, string" parameters it would be: array('%d', '%f', '%s')

Comment: @Sasa1234 the insert function uses _insert_replace_helper, which in turn uses $this->query( $this->prepare( $sql, $values ) ); So it does take care of sqli, as good as it can. I would use $wpdb->prefix infront of the table name though.

Comment: Good answer but misses the parameters for sanitation as @Mastrianni points out

Answer (score 26):

Just use `wpdb->insert(tablename, coloumn, format)` and wp will prepare that's query

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert("wp_submitted_form", array(
   "name" => $name,
   "email" => $email,
   "phone" => $phone,
   "country" => $country,
   "course" => $course,
   "message" => $message,
   "datesent" => $now ,
));
?>
```

Comment: You should add it whenever you want. Usually after your data has been populated.

Answer (score 9):

**Try this**

I recently leaned about `$wpdb->prepare` [HERE](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and added into our Free Class Booking plugin, plugin approved on wordpress.org and will live soon:

```
global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "submitted_form";

$name     = "Kumkum"; //string value use: %s
$email    = "kumkum@gmail.com"; //string value use: %s
$phone    = "3456734567"; //numeric value use: %d
$country  = "India"; //string value use: %s
$course   = "Database"; //string value use: %s
$message  = "hello i want to read db"; //string value use: %s
$now      = new DateTime(); //string value use: %s
$datesent = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //string value use: %s

$sql = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `$tablename` (`name`, `email`, `phone`, `country`, `course`, `message`, `datesent`) values (%s, %s, %d, %s, %s, %s, %s)", $name, $email, $phone, $country, $course, $message, $datesent);

$wpdb->query($sql);
```

Thanks
-Frank

Answer (score 8):

## The recommended way (as noted [in codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/)):

```
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array('column_name_1'=>'hello', 'other'=> 123), array( '%s', '%d' ) );
```

So, you'd better to sanitize values - ALWAYS CONSIDER THE SECURITY.

Comment: useful example with extra 3rd parameter

Answer (score 5):

You have to check your `quotes` properly,

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO `wp_submitted_form`      
       (`name`,`email`,`phone`,`country`,`course`,`message`,`datesent`) 
 values ($name, $email, $phone, $country, $course, $message, $datesent)");
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

**OR** you can use like,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_submitted_form`
          (`name`,`email`,`phone`,`country`,`course`,`message`,`datesent`) 
   values ($name, $email, $phone, $country, $course, $message, $datesent)";

$wpdb->query($sql);
```

Read http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: I believe wpdb->prepare requires 2 parameters. Something like this should work: $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO `wp_submitted_form`      
       (`name`,`email`,`phone`,`country`,`course`,`message`,`datesent`) 
 VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", $name, $email, $phone, $country, $course, $message, $datesent);  Also, without using a prepare statement or a wpdb->insert, how is your second answer not vulnerable to sql injection?

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your **SQL** :

You can construct your sql like this :

```
$wpdb->prepare(
 "INSERT INTO `wp_submitted_form` 
   (`name`,`email`,`phone`,`country`,`course`,`message`,`datesent`) 
   values ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$country', 
         '$course', '$message', '$datesent')"
 );
```

You can also use `$wpdb->insert()`

```
$wpdb->insert('table_name', input_array())
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\new-saraf-travels\wp-content\plugins\submitted-form\submitted-form.php on line 50

Comment: @Nida Did you change your sql  query? I think you have missed `;`

Comment: Better to use $wpdb-insert(), see responses above.

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wpdb;
$insert = $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `front-post`(`id`, `content`) VALUES ('$id', '$content')");
```

Comment: Stylistically better, simpler, and much safer to use $wpdb->insert() as detailed in a few other answers.  This isn't "wrong", it just doesn't make good use of $wpdb.  Sorry to dredge up an old article, but this is really important as use of $wpdb->query() can lead to failure to prepare.  Also, without using insert() you'd have to fiddle to get any autoincrement key. See user examples in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress you should always use `$wpdb->prefix.'yourtablename'` as a table-name instead of hardcoding it.

When the WordPress installation gets copied or moved and the database-prefix gets changed, the code would still work with this change. The way the accepted answer is written, it would crash.

Answer (score -9):

```
$wpdb->query("insert into ".$table_name." (name, email, country, country, course, message, datesent) values ('$name','$email', '$phone', '$country', '$course', '$message', )");
```

Comment: Never, ever use this, this is how mysql injection happens.