# SQL - INSERT INTO - adding few extra empty rows to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, gravityforms

I am trying to pull field entries from a Gravity Form submission into my MySQL database. My table in the database is called 'events', and currently I am pulling two fields (title, department):

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_17", "input_fields", 10, 2);
function input_fields($entry, $form){
   global $connection;
          $title = $entry['1'];
          $department = $entry['3'];

      $query = "INSERT INTO events(title, department) VALUES ('$title', '$department')";
      $result = $connection->query($query);
}
add_shortcode( 'form_test_shortcode', 'input_fields');
```

Every time I submit this form, a few empty rows are being added to my 'events' table in the database. How can I submit this form, so that only the fields I have specified are entered into the database, and no empty rows show up?

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: _Note:_ PHPMyAdmin is only a web based database management tool for managing MySQL databases. Unless you're modifying that applications core files, your application has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Since you seem to be using WordPress, you should use their dababase features (`$wpdb`) and send the values as parameters. Here's a good post about how to use it for inserting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096555/how-to-insert-data-using-wpdb?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson, thanks for the response, and the link to the post for WP. I'll look into this. So the empty rows are also showing up because of this issue?

Comment: No, that's just for security. There isn't really enough info for us to know why that happens. Do some debugging, like logging how often that function is getting called etc.