# Can not get results using $wpdb

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have following code in which I am using `$wpdb` but it is not displaying the data what I want!

```
<?php
        function perform_database_action(){
            global $wpdb;
            $data= array('col1'=>$value1,'col2'=>$value2,'col3'=>$value3);
            $format = array('%s','%s','%s');
            $wpdb->insert('table_name', $data, $format);
        }
?>
```

Can anyone help me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I assume by 'displaying' you mean in your table, but this link will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096555/how-to-insert-data-using-wpdb

Comment: Is the table called "table_name" ?! no prefix ( $wpdb->prefix ) ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing `$value1`, `$value2`, `$value3` to your function.

```
<?php
    function perform_database_action($value1, $value2, $value3){
        global $wpdb;
        $data= array('col1'=>$value1,'col2'=>$value2,'col3'=>$value3);
        $format = array('%s','%s','%s');
        $wpdb->insert('table_name', $data, $format);
    }
?>
```