# How to edit a cutsom Wordpress database from a custom form

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to make a custom form in Wordpress that will perform insertions into an existing SQL table. I've been staring at this for multiple days now and can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The table name is: centrestable
It has two columns: centreName and centreState.

My understanding is that the proper way to do this is using the wpdb->insert function. But I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix.'centrestable';
$data = array('centreName' => 'foo', 'centreState' => 'bar');
$wpdb->insert($table,$data);
```

The second way I know of doing this is using SQL query. The only way I can get this to work is if I don't use my variables:

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO `centrestable` (`centreName`, `centreState`) VALUES ('help','me') " ) );
```

The above code works, the below code does not:

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 'INSERT INTO `centrestable` (`centreName`, `centreState`) VALUES ('. $centreName.','. $centreState. ')'  ));
```

Any help would be greatly accepted. I'm about to go crazy or cry because of this :(

My full code is here. I'm using it in a template, under my theme.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: WordPress-Form
 */
 get_header();
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 
 ?>
 <form action="" method="post">
    <label for="centre-name">Centre Name
        <input id="centre-name" type="text" name="centre-name" value="">
    </label>
    <label for="centre-state">State
        <input id="centre-state" type="text" name="centre-state" value="">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
 <?php
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r( $_POST );

 
 if ( isset( $_POST['submit'])) {
     $centreName = ( ! empty( $_POST['centre-name'])) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['centre-name']) : '';
     $centreState = ( ! empty ($_POST['centre-state'])) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['centre-state']) : '';
     
     echo $centreName;
     echo $centreState;
     echo "this if";
     
    global $wpdb;
    
    /* TEST 1 */
    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'centrestable';
    $data = array('centreName' => 'foo', 'centreState' => 'bar');
    $wpdb->insert($table,$data);
    
    /* TEST 2 */ 
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 'INSERT INTO `centrestable` (`centreName`, `centreState`) VALUES ('. $centreName.','. $centreState. ')'  ));

    /* TEST 2 */
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO `centrestable` (`centreName`, `centreState`) VALUES ('help','me') " ) );
          

     

 }
```

Comment: this icode is vulnerable to sql injection , using prepared in that way doen't help to avoid it

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096555/how-to-insert-data-using-wpdb

Comment: Can you verify the table field names, and types?